# would you choose the speed of an algorithm over its efficient use of memory?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, memory

In a past examination paper, there was a question that gave two methods to check if int[] A contained all the same values as int[] B (two unsorted arrays of size N), an engineer had to decide which implementation he would use.

The first method used a single for loop with a nested call to linear search; its asymptotic run time was calculated to be theta(n^2) and additional memory usage for creating copies of A and B is around (N*4N + 4N) bytes

The second method used an additional int[] C, that is a copy of B, which is sorted. A for loop is used with a nested binary search; it's asymptotic run time was calculated as theta(nlog(n^2)) and additional memory usage for creating copies of A and B is around (4N + 4N + N*4N + 4N) bytes (the first two 4N's are due to C being a copy of B, and the subsequent copy of C being created in the sort(C); function)

The final question asks which implementation the Engineer should use, I believe that a faster algorithm would be the better option, as for larger inputs the faster algorithm would cut the time of computation drastically, although the draw back is that with larger inputs, he runs the risk of an OutOfMemory Error, I understand one could state either method, depending on the size of the arrays, although my question is, in the majority of cases, which implementation is the better implementation?

Comment: I suppose there's not _correct_ answer to this. It more or less depends on the case.

Comment: choosing algorithms, is that your question? what is related to programming?

Comment: My question is, is the speed of an algorithm more important than its efficient use of memory or vice versa, the exam question above was merely what provoked the question

Comment: How often is the code called, and how large are the data sets? When in doubt, I always chose *readability* over speed and memory efficiency.

Comment: the two methods are snippets from a class, so there is no main or tester, the question simply asked "_Which of the two implementations would you advise the engineer to pick and why? what would be the benefits and drawbacks of this choice"_ I explained my choice and the benefits and drawbacks, but in an overall scale of things, I was wondering which is actually the better choice

Comment: Sorry, delete my above comment by mistake. The question was, if there is an mistake in the complexity.

Comment: I think this is really one of those cases where there's not a right answer of "this is what you should usually do." You just have to know the tradeoffs, and for a given situation, figure out what works for that situation. If I asked you if I should get a sedan or a pickup truck, the only answer you could reasonably give me is "depends on what you need."

Comment: I guess it is down to the context and situation, thank you all for the answers

Comment: Why is this no opion-based? It can be proofed which alg. is better. The question is formulated in that way that one should think the second alg. consumes a lot more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first alg. has complexity of theta (n^2) and the second of theta ( n log(n^2)).

Hence, the second one is much faster for `n` great enough.

As you mentioned, the memory usage comes into account and one would argue that the second one consumes a lot more memory but that is not true.

The first alg. consumes: n*4n+4n= 4n^2 + 4n

The second alg. consumes: 4n+4n+4n+n*4n=4n^2+12n

Suppose `n` is equal to `1000` then the first alg consumes `4004000` and the second `4012000` memory. So there is no big difference in memory consumption between the two algorithms.

So, from a memory consumption perspective it does not really matter which alg. you choose and in terms of complexity they both consumes `theta (n^2)` memory.

Answer (score 1):

A relevant question to many a programmer, but the answer depends entirely on the context. If the software runs on a system with a little memory, then the algorithm with a smaller footprint will likely be better. On the other hand, a real-time system needs speed; so the faster algorithm would likely be better.

It is important to also recognize the more subtle issues that arise during execution, e.g. when the additional memory requirements of the faster algorithm force the system to use paging and, in turn, slow down execution.

Thus, it is important to understand *in-context* the benefit-cost trade off for each algorithm. And as always, emphasize code readability and sound algorithm design/integration.

Comment: Of course, the context is important but what I think about the question is, that the trainee should learn that linear terms and constant terms do not matter when there is a term with a higher exponent.

Comment: @Peter I don't entirely (dis)agree because it still depends on context. In some contexts (e.g. Real time systems) a constant factor can be critical. The issue is the OP asks,"**in the majority of cases**, which is the better implementation?" This is a fundamentally flawed view: there is no one-size-fits all answer. Nonetheless, you are right: if the OP doesn't understand the difference between O(n) and O(n^2), there's other issues at hand